# Something like P.S. but before the text?

Tags: letter-writing

I wrote a letter (electronic) to someone yesterday but could not send it and fell asleep. Now if I want to send it today it will make less sense as it was written in context of yesterday. So I have added something like -
"I wanted to send it last night but things got delayed and I eventually feel asleep after taking a tablet.
Anyways here we go." But what if it was a hard copy letter, in that case would going by with P.S.or P.P.S. be my only choice?

Should I just write *Note* in front of it, or is there something like PRE scriptum, that I can mention before the letter starts.

Comment: If it were a normal letter, you wouldn't write anything, because the letter would take days to arrive anyway. And if it's an email, you also don't write anything. If it no longer makes sense, you either reword it accordingly, or just don't send it at all.

Comment: @RegDwigнt It was written in an emotional mood, which will be lost on editing it in today's context.

Comment: If you are sending it using a medium which allows attachments (such as conventional email) you could copy the content, paste it into a word processor or text document, save the document then send the explanation as a message with the actual letter as an attachment.

Comment: @BoldBen No it is normal text message.

Comment: @BhaskarVashishth By "normal text message" I assume you mean SMS on a phone, I was a bit confused by your use of the word 'letter' to describe it. Even then, if your device allows you to change fonts or colours in a text you could insert an explanatory paragraph in a different font and/or colour before the body of the text and then send it.

Comment: @BoldBen thanks. Italics should work.

Comment: If it's informal you can add explanations however you like. If it's formal or even informal but not going to a friend or family member then I don't think it's a good idea to mention taking medication, just add something like, "Note: I wrote this last night but wasn't able to send it until this morning."